# SharePoint 2013 Certifications

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

It's been few days that I have decided to start preparing for my SharePoint Certifications.

But, I am facing a lot of difficulty as in from where do I start?

My interest are in SharePoint Administration, SharePoint Designer, Workflows**(All in SP2013)**.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main certifications before you can try the master in Redmond ;)

**MCSE SharePoint:**
Solutions Expert - 
Take the MCSE if you want to proof that you are a good SharePoint administrator:
http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx

**MCSD SharePoint Applications:**
Solution Developer - 
Take the MCSD if you want to show that you are able to develop Custom Solutions build on top of SharePoint:
https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx

**MCSM SharePoint**
Solutions Master - 
The master (only if you are very very very experienced):
https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsm-sharepoint-certification.aspx

The best way to start is to gain some experience. After that you can search for brain dumps to prepare yourself for the certification. And if you want you can take part at a classroom trainig.

Go to the prometric website to find a partner near you where you can take the exam: https://www.prometric.com/en-us/Pages/home.aspx

Comment: Hi hupseb.. Thank you so much for your response. Yes, I will go for the second Certification that you have mentioned i.e. the MCSD SharePoint Applications as I have already given the 070-480 exam.

Comment: You are welcome. Mark it as answer if it was helpful ;)